# System.out.println to separate lines in String

Tags: java

I want to create cells for this spread sheet. The thing is for my toString() method, I created a variable ret and I'm adding onto it. The problem I'm having is how do I add a System.out.println(); to ret? I'm coding the spread sheet line by line using for loops but once I'm done with printing the first line, the second line that I want to print after the first line on a seperate line is being printed on the first line because I'm not sure how to ret += System.out.println();

How do i seperate the two lines?

This is part of my code:

```
String ret = "";
String alph = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
ret += ("             |");

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++) {
    ret += ("      " + alph.charAt(i) + "      |");
}

System.out.println();
ret += ("-------------+");

for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++) {
    ret += ("-------------+");
}
```

Comment: Instead of doing the SOP, do `ret += System.getProperty("line.separator");` as this will provide you the correct "next line" characters based on the system you're on as some use `\n` and some use `\r\n` and you won't have to worry which one

Answer (score 1):

```
String ret = "";
    String alph = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    ret += ("             |");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++) {
        ret += ("      " + alph.charAt(i) + "      |");
    }
   ret += "\n";
    ret += ("-------------+");
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i ++) {
        ret += ("-------------+");
    }
```

Comment: Instead of just providing a code sample, please provide *what* the solution is so they don't have to try figuring it out what the difference is

Answer (score 1):

Where you want the line break to be, you need to add a new line character.  This may be `\n` or `\r\n` depending on the operating system.   You can also use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to determine the correct new line character.

```
ret += System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a newline character `'\n'` to the string.

Replace this:

```
System.out.println();
```

with this:

```
ret += "\n";
```

When it gets printed, a newline character starts a new line (hence the name). They're also used in text files to separate lines.

Comment: Oh my goodness! I totally forgot about the \n! Thank you so much